# HERESDK Flutter - WayPoint passThrough only if no deviation

Tags: flutter, here-api

I'm building an app with the Here Flutter SDK with routing from point A to point B for pedestrian.

Along this route, i want to specify GeoCoordinates / radius / roads where i would like the route to pass through.
I don't want these GeoCoordinates to be mandatory, i want the route to be as fast as possible (or as short as possible), without any deviation.
Like a hint to shape the route.
So if the coordinates is not on the "main road route" i don't want it to be part of the route.

I have tried with Waypoint stopover and passthrough but it makes some deviations.

[image]

```
GeoCoordinates startCoordinates = GeoCoordinates(startLatLng.latitude, startLatLng.longitude);
    GeoCoordinates destinationCoordinates = GeoCoordinates(arrivalLatLng.latitude, arrivalLatLng.longitude);

    // start
    List<Waypoint> waypoints = [];
    var startWaypoint = Waypoint.withDefaults(startCoordinates);
    waypoints.add(startWaypoint);

   
    var waypointsToPrioritize = _manageWaypointsToPrioritize(reportsToPrioritized);
    waypoints.addAll(waypointsToPrioritize);

    // destination
    var destinationWaypoint = Waypoint.withDefaults(destinationCoordinates);
    waypoints.add(destinationWaypoint);

    // manage route options
    var pedestrianOptions = PedestrianOptions();
    var routeOptions = pedestrianOptions.routeOptions;
    routeOptions.alternatives = 1;
    routeOptions.optimizationMode = OptimizationMode.fastest;
    pedestrianOptions.routeOptions = routeOptions;

    // manage route text options
    var routeTextOptions = RouteTextOptions();
    var currentLocale = Platform.localeName;
    currentLocale = currentLocale.replaceAll("_", "");
    routeTextOptions.language = LanguageCode.values.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.name.toLowerCase() == currentLocale.toLowerCase()) ?? LanguageCode.enUs;
    pedestrianOptions.textOptions = routeTextOptions;

    // manage avoidance options
    var avoidanceOptions = _manageAvoidanceOptions(reportsToAvoid);
    pedestrianOptions.avoidanceOptions = avoidanceOptions;

    _routingEngine?.calculatePedestrianRoute(waypoints, pedestrianOptions, (RoutingError? routingError, List<here.Route>? routeList) async {
...
}

var waypoint = Waypoint.withDefaults(GeoCoordinates(report.latitude!, report.longitude!));
waypoint.type = WaypointType.passThrough;
```

On this given example there are none avoidanceOptions specified.

Is there a way to shape the route with hint without passing through ?
Should i handle them after the response and remove them if they are not on the main route ?

Answer (score 0):

As listed in the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/4.13.5.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#shape-the-route-with-additional-waypoints), there can be two types of waypoints:

- `STOPOVER`: The default waypoint type. It is guaranteed that this point will be passed, therefore it appears in the list of maneuver instructions, and splits the route into separate route sections.
- `PASS_THROUGH`: May not appear in the maneuver instructions list and is rather treated as a hint to shape the route, for example, as a result of a touch input. This type will not split the route into separate sections.

That means that any waypoint of type `WaypointType.passThrough` can be passed in the resulting route, but there is **no guarantee** that it will be passed.

The resulting `Route` object does not contain any information on waypoints that are not part of the route, so there should be no need to filter them out or to remove them. **Routes** contain only `RoutePlaces` as part of `Sections` which contain `mapMatchedCoordinates` and `originalCoordinates`. If the waypoint was becoming part of the route you can compare it to the `originalCoordinates`.

During guidance, there is also a `MilestoneListener` that allows to notify you, when a waypoint has been passed.

If you are looking for other ways to "shape" the route, then `AvoidanceOptions` with blocked zones or roads may be considered.